# How can I go about trying to use onSnapshot in my user context? I would like to get real time updates of notifications (like facebook etc.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to get realtime notifications or user profile updates from firebase. I understand I need to use `onSnapshot` however, I tried before and it wasn't unsubscribing. If you logged out and loggin in as another user, it would sometimes get the profile data of the user logged in previously, which is an AWFUL bug to have.

So basically I have two context providers:

**AuthProvider** (stores (`currentUser`) auth email, uid etc.)

**UserProvider** (stores (`userData`) firestore data, such as profile picture, username, first name, surname etc.)

How can I go about subscribing to the `userData` information but then ensuring it unsubscribes when the auth state changes? As I have failed to this at every attempt.

*AuthProvider:*

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function logout() {
    return auth.signOut();
  }

  function resetPassword(email) {
    return auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  }

  function updateEmail(email) {
    return currentUser.updateEmail(email);
  }

  function updatePassword(password) {
    return currentUser.updatePassword(password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    setSearchQueryState,
    login,
    signup,
    logout,
    resetPassword,
    updateEmail,
    updatePassword,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

*UserProvider:*

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getUserByUserId } from "../services/firebase";
import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export function useUser() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function UserProvider({ children }) {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(async () => {
    if (currentUser) {
      const data = await getUserByUserId(currentUser.uid);
      setUserData(data);
      setLoading(false);
    } else {
      setUserData();
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  const value = {
    userData,
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The firebase call I imported into `UserProvider`

```
import { auth, db } from "../firebase";

// get user from the firestore where userId === userId (passed from the auth)
export async function getUserByUserId(userID) {
  const result = await db.collection("users").doc(userID).get();
  const user = result.data();

  return user;
}
```

***Thank you in advance!***

So currently, when this useEffect in my userAuth is causing me to sometimes log in as other users:

```
    import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
    import { getUserByUserId } from "../services/firebase";
    import { useAuth } from "./AuthContext";
    
    const UserContext = React.createContext();
    
    export function useUser() {
      return useContext(UserContext);
    }
    
    export function UserProvider({ children }) {
      const { currentUser } = useAuth();
      const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    
      //THIS USE EFFECT LISTENS TO SNAPSHOT DATA--------
      useEffect(async () => {
        let usersnapshot;
        if (currentUser) {
          usersnapshot = db.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid);
          usersnapshot.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            setUserData(doc.data());
            setLoading(false);
          });
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
          setUserData();
          return usersnapshot;
        }
      }, [currentUser]);
    //--------------------------
      const value = {
        userData,
      };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `currentUser` changes in the `UserProvider`?

Comment: @TarikHuber it does indeed! I just signed out and currentUser is now null

Comment: Can you show how you use the `onSnapshot`? How does your datase rules look like? A user should not be able to get data from another. If that is the case it looks like a bug in the react state management.

Comment: @TarikHuber sure thing! ill edit my post now, thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to detach the listener when the `currentUser` changes. Can you try to change this part of your code:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
        let usersnapshot;
        let unsubscribe;
        if (currentUser) {
          usersnapshot = db.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid);
          unsubscribe = usersnapshot.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            setUserData(doc.data());
            setLoading(false);
          });
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
          setUserData();
          return usersnapshot;
        }
        return unsubscribe;
      }, [currentUser]);
```

What we are doing here that we save the `unsubscribe` call to a variable in the `useEffect` and call it when the `currentUser` changes. That should unsibscribe the `onSnapshot` each time a user changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it's still switching back to the old account sometimes!

Comment: Can you somehow show what exactly happens.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use Firestore rules, to deny any request for user data by different users, e.g.:

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
         match /users/{user} {
          allow read, write: if
            request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.ownerID
         }
      }
    }
```

Second, I am not sure if your unsubscribe call works like this in a useEffect. instead of `return unsubscribe;` try `return () => unsubscribe();`